# Prevent Users From Calling incrementPostCount Function in Firebase Independently of addPost

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Let say I have these 2 fields in my firebase database.

```
user: {
  postCount: 2
  posts: [
    {title: hello, content: world},
    {title: hello again, content: world}
  ]
}
```

I want the user to have permission to update his posts. but I don't want him to be able to update his post count. I want the post counts to always represent the number of posts and prevent the user from cheating it.

How can I do this in firebase? Is it possible with front end javascript only? If not what would be the option that requires the least server side code possible?

This is the code I'm using but it doesn't prevent users from cheating and just calling the increment function by themselves infinite times.

```
const push = (objectToInsert, firebasePath) => {
    const key = firebase.database().ref().child(firebasePath).push().key
    let updates = {}
    updates[firebasePath + key] = objectToInsert
    firebase.database().ref().update(updates)
}

const increment = (firebasePath) => {
    const ref = firebase.database().ref(firebasePath)
    ref.transaction( (value) => {
        value++
        return value
    })
}

push(post, `/${user}/${posts}/`)
increment(`/${user}/${postCount}`)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring you to firebase rules:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/#section-authorization

Either you set the rules on each of the user properties based on your security setup and keep the structure as you mentioned, Or move the counts to another node and set the rules (ex. user_post_counts).

Comment: How would the rules help me in this case? I need to let the user only be able to increment once after a new post was made. I can't think of a combination of rules or nodes that would let me accomplish that.

Comment: Prevent users with other ids from writing to this node. Allow only the user to "read" the property you want them to read

Comment: Specifically set write access to null or admin level and read to the user or all  users if it is a public property

Comment: So the only way is to have the admin increment the property which means it would need to be server side?